# I R, plotly/highlight, about the "brush colour" setting

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, highlight

I R, plotly/highlight, i have two questions

1.How to remove the "Brush color" (remove the text and dropbox)
2.How to change/add the avaiable colour settings for "Brush color"

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
d <- highlight_key(txhousing, ~city)
p <- ggplot(d, aes(date, median, group = city)) + geom_line()
gg <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = "city") 
highlight(gg, dynamic = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide data, use `dput`. W.r.t (1): `+ theme_classic()` or `+ theme_minimal()`?

Comment: the data from  ggplot2 package “ggplot2::txhousing” . Thanks

Comment: This is a good question, having the same problem, even when setting color=NULL in the highlight() function

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation on highlight from plotly. You can also read more here:

https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html#linking-animated-views

which is where the example comes from.

Looks like the `dynamic` param controls whether there is a brush color box or not. And the `color` param controls the color options. If you pass `TRUE` to `dynamic=` and don't provide enough colours plotly will automatically load in the default four.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# load the `txhousing` dataset
data(txhousing, package = "ggplot2")

# declare `city` as the SQL 'query by' column
tx <- highlight_key(txhousing, ~city)

# initiate a plotly object
base <- plot_ly(tx, color = I("black")) %>% 
  group_by(city)

# create a time series of median house price
time_series <- base %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~date, y = ~median)

highlight(
  time_series, 
  on = "plotly_click", 
  dynamic = FALSE, # should a widget for changing selection colours be included
  selectize = TRUE,
  persistent = FALSE,
  color = "orange" # provide colour or vector of colour option
)
```